# How do I replace a specific character in a .srt file in Notepad++, if there are multiple occurrances of it and I want to leave the rest untouched?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have multiple .srt files that were generated in a way they are not recognized by the video player as their text formatting is different.

Original:

```
00:00:01:02 --> 00:00:04:16
```

What I need:

```
00:00:01,02 --> 00:00:04,16
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

---

I just had time to try the suggested solution and it doesn't work.
Here is a more detailed sample of what I need:

Original:

```
00:00:00:02 --> 00:00:21:15
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1
00:00:21:21 --> 00:00:42:23
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet2
00:00:43:01 --> 00:01:01:22
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet3
```

I need:

```
00:00:00,02 --> 00:00:21,15
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1
00:00:21,21 --> 00:00:42,23
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet2
00:00:43,01 --> 00:01:01,22
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet3
```

So in each line that have the timing numbers, I need to replace the 3rd and the 6th `:` with `,`.

Comment: .srt should actually be padded to three places after the comma [ty to the French originators of the srt format that we use a comma rather than a decimal point… but hey, their format, their call ;)

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:(\d+\s|\d+$)`
- Replace with: `,$1`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:** `:(\d+\s|\d+$)` finds colon followed by digits and spaces or colon followed by digits at the end of a line. Capture the digits and spaces. Replace what was found with a comma followed by the captured group (the digit(s)).

Comment: I'd use `:(\d+)$` to deal with unknown number of digits.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ErwinDirks You can mark the question as answered. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: @ErwinDirks See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked great!